# Error: No matching function for call to memsetNincr

Tags: c++

The function memsetNincr is to fill an array of size "size" with integers, each one valued one greater than the last. I've been having this problem with functions lately...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void memsetNincr(int, int, int);

int main()
{
    int size, initVal;

    cout << "Enter size of array followed by the value of its' first element: \n";
    cin >> size >> initVal;

    int array[size];

    cout << memsetNincr(array, size, initVal) << endl;
    return 0;
}

void memsetNincr(int array[], int howmany, int startingVal)
{
    int i;

    array[0] = startingVal;

    for (i=0; i<=howmany; i++)
    {
        array[i] = array[i-1]-1;
        cout << array[i] << "  ";
    }
}
```

Comment: `int array[size];` is illegal in ISO C++. The dimensions of a C-style array must be known at compile-time.  Some compilers implement an extension (imho, a poor one) that makes this code sort-of work as expected in some circumstances.

Comment: Your loop inside `memsetNincr` writes out of bounds, and reads out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

`cout` expects a stream or something that can be casted to a stream. Your function returns void, and void cannot be casted. Either change the function to return a string or stringstream object or just call it outside of cout.

Edit: With calling it outside of `cout` I mean something like this:

```
int main()
  {
  int size, initVal;

  cout << "Enter size of array followed by the value of its' first element: \n";
  cin >> size >> initVal;

  int array[size];

  memsetNincr(array, size, initVal);
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first run `i = 0`

```
array[i] = array[i-1]-1;
```

so

```
array[0] = array[0-1]-1;
```

so

```
array[0] = array[-1]-1; -> error

(i=1; i<=howmany; i++)
```

should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

change `cout << memsetNincr(array, size, initVal) << endl;` to `memsetNincr(array, size, initVal);`

change

```
for (i=0; i<=howmany; i++)
{
    array[i] = array[i-1]-1;
    cout << array[i] << "  ";
}
```

to

```
for (i=1; i<=howmany; i++)
{
    array[i] = array[i-1]-1;
    cout << array[i] << "  ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

======1======

Your function declaration is not right, the parameter `int array[]` or `int *array`.

```
void memsetNincr(int array[], int howmany, int startingVal);
```

or
    void memsetNincr(int *array, int howmany, int startingVal);

======2======

the `memsetNincr` is void, it meams that function does not return any value, so it can't by print by `cout` or `printf`.

```
cout << memsetNincr(array, size, initVal) << endl;
```

should by write

```
memsetNincr(array, size, initVal);
```

this is your codes

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void memsetNincr(int*, int, int);

int main()
{
    int size, initVal;

    cout << "Enter size of array followed by the value of its' first element: \n";
    cin >> size >> initVal;

    int array[size];

    //cout << memsetNincr(array, size, initVal) << endl;
    memsetNincr(array, size, initVal);

    return 0;
}

void memsetNincr(int array[], int howmany, int startingVal)
{
    int i;

    array[0] = startingVal;

    for (i=0; i<=howmany; i++)
    {
        array[i] = array[i-1]-1;
        cout << array[i] << "  ";
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no Variable Length Arrays in C++. So the size of the array shall be a constant expression.

You could use standard class `std::vector` declared in header `<vector>` if the number of elements is given by the user.

Function `memsetNincr` accepts the first argument of an array type. So at least it first parameter should be declared like

```
void memsetNincr(int *, int, int);
```

or

```
void memsetNincr(int [], int, int);
```

Moreover the function has return type `void`. So you may not use it in statements like this

```
cout << memsetNincr(array, size, initVal) << endl;
```

You should use a separate loop to output the elements of the array.

Take into account that if the array has `howmany`  elements then the corresponding loop will look like

```
for (i=0; i < howmany; i++)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

because the valid range of indices is `[0, howmany-1]`